# Issues with loading TinyMCE

Tags: cakephp, tinymce

I've placed the TinyMCE folder under my plugins folder however facing some issues with loading it.

I can use TinyMCE if I load the JS file from [tinymce.com](http://tinymce.com) using

```
script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"
```

However, the code below would not load the tinymce plugin. Is there something wrong with my linking?

```
script src="/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min"
```

Comment: Are you use cakephp html helper? for errors look on browser console

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```